# Linux command line extracting name from text

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

how can i extract basename of software where form is like :

software-1.2.3-vd.ext 
OR
soft-ware-1.2.3-vd.ext

i need to extract software or soft-ware, everything before the version.
I have look with regular expression but dont know how to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: google grep examples - that should help!

Comment: Have the utility you are getting the software names from only print the name. `rpm` can easily do this, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed):

```
echo 'software-1.2.3-vd.ext'  | sed 's/\-[0-9].*//'  # software
echo 'soft-ware-1.2.3-vd.ext' | sed 's/\-[0-9].*//'  # soft-ware
```

Comment: That work great, thank, now i can check what that mean exactly.

Comment: You are welcome. It removes the first `-` followed by a number, and every character after it

Answer (score 1):

Pure BASH solution:

```
s="software-1.2.3-vd.ext"
echo "${s%%-[0-9]*}"
software

s="soft-ware-1.2.3-vd.ext"
echo "${s%%-[0-9]*}"
soft-ware
```

Comment: +1 for not spawning an extra process

Answer (score 0):

With the command `basename` (which is specially meant for this purpose)